# Punya and Papa and how swabhava affects them

Tags: mahabharata, moksha, gunas

If god controls everything, why does a person get punya or papa even though that person has no control over anything ?

Is swabhava just the choice that we make ( which is greatly affected by sattva, rajas and tamas proportions present in a jiva) which decides whether the choice resulted in benefitting the world or harming dharma causing that person to get punya or papa.

I believe Bhimasena gives an answer to this when Dharmaraj asked what is more important between Dharma, Artha and kaama, where Bhimasena tells that Kaama , the desire to be with god is the most important. But the answer is not fulfilling.